# react checkbox onChange to call function is check state is true in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am exploring the react `onChange` feature. The functionality I would like to do is
when checkbox is selected, I would like to update local data to add some value
when checkbox is unselected, I would like to just populate the original data
the code I have seems do the reverse of what I want. any can provide some guideline?

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-breeze-w259y?file=/src/App.js)

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const localData = [{ name: "apple", phone: 12345 }];
  const [check, setCheck] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState(localData);
  const handleOnChange = () => {
    setCheck(!check);
    check ? setData([...data, { name: "amazon", phone: 222 }]) : setData(data);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <p>
        <input type="checkbox" check onChange={handleOnChange}></input>
      </p>
      <p>{JSON.stringify(data)}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `setCheck` runs asyncranously. So in the function `handleOnChange`, right after `setCheck(!check)`, `check`'s value has not been set to the new value yet.

You could use an effect here since you want the side-effect of changing `data` from changing `check`. This way, whenever `check` is done changing, the effect triggers:

```js
const handleOnChange = () => {
    setCheck(!check);
};
useEffect(() => {
  check &&
      setData((previous) => [...previous, { name: "amazon", phone: 222 }]);
}, [check]);
```

Updated sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-rain-hmhkk

Comment: gotcha, thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of using two states, that solution will give you more problems when you want to add more options.

I would go for an approach similar to this one:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

const localData = [{ name: "apple", phone: 12345 }];
const extraData = [{ name: "amazon", phone: 222 }];

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(localData);

  const handleOnChange = (item) => {
    if (!data.find(({ name }) => name === item.name)) setData([...data, item]);
    else setData(data.filter(({ name }) => name !== item.name));
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <p>
        {extraData.map((item) => {
          return (
            <input
              key={item.name}
              type="checkbox"
              checked={data.includes(({ name }) => name === item.name)}
              onChange={() => handleOnChange(item)}
            />
          );
        })}
      </p>
      <p>{JSON.stringify(data)}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This will allow you to add more checkboxes in the future.

Answer (score -2):

So, you want the data to be added to `data` when the checkbox IS checked? Just invert the condition of the ternary that you use in `handleOnChange`:

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const localData = [{ name: "apple", phone: 12345 }];
  const [check, setCheck] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState(localData);
  const handleOnChange = () => {
    setCheck(!check);
    !check ? setData([...data, { name: "amazon", phone: 222 }]) : setData(data);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <p>
        <input type="checkbox" check onChange={handleOnChange}></input>
      </p>
      <p>{JSON.stringify(data)}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```